# Does MS Access update the data on the clipboard from a query when the data in the database changes?

Tags: microsoft-access, clipboard, query

I was just debugging a macro in MS Access, and when it hit the breakpoint ran a query and I copied the data from it to the clipboard.  Some of the values were null before stepping to the next step, then I ran the next step which ran a query which changed the data I had on the clipboard.  I then pasted the data and the values that were null before had been changed by the query...leading to a rather large WTF on my part when I pasted the data.

So my question is, does MSAccess update the data on the clipboard when it changes in the database?  That's the only explanation I have for what occurred there.

Comment: Are you copying the data to the clipboard as part of the macro, or are you using the GUI after the macro is done running?

Comment: The latter I'm using the GUI after I take another step in the macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a quick table, threw some garble in there, created a query, copied the query, pasted the data into Notepad, changed the original table, re-ran the query, and re-pasted the data into Notepad.  Updating the query didn't update my Clipboard.

So I would say from that, the answer is no: Access does not update Clipboard data when the originally copied data changes.

Comment: No I didn't update the query I updated the table where the query got it's data from.

Comment: That's what I was saying.  After copying the query, I updated the table (added another row and changed some of the data in the first one), ran the same query again, and re-pasted without re-copying the query.  The clipboard did not automatically update to match the updated query.  I had to manually re-copy the query to get the new data in the clipboard.